# Allow everyone write access through python

Tags: python, multiplatform

So, let's start with the base problem;

Program writes a file as user of elevated rights.

Later:
Same program tries to overwrite the file without elevated rights.

In Windows this clashes with:

> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '`filepath`'

- I need this to work on **Linux/Windows/Mac**, though it seems like
  windows is the only one exhibiting this issue currently, so I tried
  to fix it with windows methods on windows. `CHMOD` doesn't work under
  windows anyway.
- So, the problem is, that the file is owned by Administrator or
  another user with extended rights when the program is run as that
  user. If I can just create the file with "`everybody write`"
  permission, then this would not be a problem.
- I found no portable way to do so in pure python. I can only remove
  the `read-only` flag but it doesn't solve the ownership issue.

So I tried win32security
However, the call to LookupAccountName is locale dependent:

```
>>> win32security.LookupAccountName(None, "Everyone")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
pywintypes.error: (1332, 'LookupAccountName', 'Zuordnungen von Kontennamen und Sicherheitskennungen wurden nicht durchgeführt.')
>>> win32security.LookupAccountName(None, "Jeder")
(<PySID object at 0x00000184AA586560>, '', 5)
```

And therefore not portable. I also found no way of manually creating the "`Everyone`" SID, the docs are rather minimal in that respect. But I might also be following the wrong rabbit hole.

Edit: If it matters, in this particular case at least, all relevant files are under "%programdata%/programname/*" in windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem went away with one of the windows updates within the 1903 timeframe. Some additional digging seems to suggest this was a bug in windows IF that system is part of a domain and ownership would fall into a domain user.